# Removing brackets from a numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Let's say I have the following array -

```
X = np.array([[0, 1,5], [3, 7,6], [11,3,2]])
```

And then I do  -

```
X[1,np.delete(range(3),0)]
```

Which gives -

```
array([7, 6])
```

Basically, I would like to be left with just -

```
7, 6
```

separated by a comma in float form (not string) if that's possible?

Thanks!

Comment: What does `float form (not string)` mean?  You want a list of two floats?  Because printing that will look like `[7.0, 6.0]`.  Is that what you want?

Comment: You're getting the string representation of your data structures mixed up with what your data structures actually represent. If you want to do math with your data, the array you have is fine. If you want to print `7, 6` to the screen or a file or something, there are various array printing and string manipulation tools available for you.

Comment: One of the things you'll need to realize is that your array has **no brackets** and **no commas** in it. Its `repr` representation has brackets and commas in it. If you want to print a different string representation of the data in your array, you need to change your printing logic, not your array.

Comment: No, it isn't possible.

Comment: `7, 6` is a different Python data structure called `tuple`.

Comment: The output you see in the python interpreter is always a string.

Answer (score 1):

Just try converting it to a list:

```
>>> X[1,np.delete(range(3),0)].tolist()
[7, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

You start with a 2d array, and select a portion.  The result is a 1d array:

```
In [83]: X = np.array([[0, 1,5], [3, 7,6], [11,3,2]]) 
In [84]: X
Out[84]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  5],
       [ 3,  7,  6],
       [11,  3,  2]])
In [85]: y = X[1,1:]
In [86]: y
Out[86]: array([7, 6])
```

That can be display in various ways.  The default array `str` display uses brackets and no comma.  The `repr` display include the `array` name

```
In [87]: str(y)
Out[87]: '[7 6]'
```

A list display still has brackets:

```
In [88]: y.tolist()
Out[88]: [7, 6]
In [98]: tuple(y)
Out[98]: (7, 6)
```

I don't know of any builtin structure that displays as numbers separated by comma and without some sort of brackets.

But if you convert each element into a string, and join them with `,` you get the plain string you want:

```
In [89]: ', '.join([str(i) for i in y])
Out[89]: '7, 6'
```

we can also format the array with `%` formatting.  This is what `np.savetxt` does when writing rows of an array to a file.

```
In [91]: '%d, %d'%tuple(y)
Out[91]: '7, 6'
In [97]: '{}, {}'.format(*y)
Out[97]: '7, 6'
```

Underlying all of this are two things:

- what's the object - array,  list, tuple, string
- how's that object being displayed.  All objects have a `str` method and a `repr` display method.  But always, there's a distinction between the object, and its display method.  Don't mistake one for the other.